# What groups are Lie groups?

Tags: lie-groups, topological-groups

We know how to tell if a topological group is a Lie group: this was famously asked by Hilbert and answered gloriously by Gleason, Montgomery and Zippin in the 50s (a locally compact topological group can be turned into a Lie group iff there is one neighborhood of 1 which does not contain a non-trivial subgroup)

> Can one tell when an abstract group is in some way a Lie group?

A natural follow up questions is, of course: if a group is Lie-sable (urgh), is it in a unique way? For comparison, a topological group which can made into a Lie group can be made in exactly one way.

Comment: Probably you don't want the discrete topology (which turns every group into a 0-dimensional Lie group)

Comment: Yup. But let's say manifolds are 2nd countable spaces, so the discrete topology would only work on countable groups.


Comment: Generally it's not a Lie group in a unique way -- the groups $\mathbb R^n$ for $n \geq 1$ are all isomorphic as groups, but not as Lie groups with their standard Lie groups structures.  

Comment: Doesn't algori's answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/62385/can-a-lie-group-as-an-abstract-group-be-given-more-than-one-topology-making-it-a
(and Kramer's paper I linked to in a comment there) at least partially answer your follow-up question? 

Comment: @Ryan, @Theo: ah, right!

Comment: @Mariano, your question is very close to a standard question in group theory, being the question of if a group is *linear* i.e. if it is realizable as a subgroup of a matrix group.   For this there's the Tits alternative. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tits_alternative

Comment: The question "in how many ways" might have an interesting answer if one excludes R^n and T^n (and other similar ones?).

Comment: @Mariano: how are you given the group? Any abstract presentation of a (connected, nontrivial) Lie group would require uncountably many generators, right? 

Comment: Qiaochu: indeed, a presentation would be continuum-big. But the question is in the abstract, so the group is not given in any concrete sense.

Comment: Does anyone know of an abstract group that is not isomorphic to a Lie group?  This seems related to the Friedlander-Milnor Conjecture, although maybe that assumes more structure than just a Lie group?

Comment: (Of course second countability puts on some set-theoretic constraints, but that's not so interesting.)

Comment: @Dan: Any positive-dimensional Lie group has elements of infinite order.

Comment: Another condition: if $G$ is a (connected) Lie group, there is a number $k$ such that every torsion subgroup contains an abelian normal subgroup of index at most $k$  (This extends Jordan's bound for $GL$; see [Dong Hoon Lee: On Torsion Subgroups of Lie Groups. Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. Vol. 55, No. 2, 1976   ])

Comment: In a Lie group $G$, every $g$ sufficiently close to the identity has the property that, for all positive integers $n$, there is an $h$ with $h^n=g$.  The subgroup generated by all such $g$ must then contain the connected component of the identity, and so has at most countable index in $G$.

For example, this shows that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (forgetting the topology) cannot be given the structure of a Lie group.  (This example is maybe not so interesting, as every torsion-free abelian Lie group is $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$, but oh well)

Comment: @Julian: +1 for your example, rather subtle since $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is abstractly isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ (as both are $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces of the same dimension). 

Comment: @Julian: 1+, why is every torsion-free abelian Lie group isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @Martin: a connected abelian Lie group is a product of an $\mathbb R^n$ and a torus, and a torus has torsion. 

Comment: Sorry, but Hilbert's question regarding Lie groups was definitely not "how to tell if a topological group is a Lie group ?", as claimed by Mariano Suarez-Alvarez. Indeed, it is sufficient to consult : F.E. Browder (Ed), Mathematical Developments Arising from Hilbert Problems. Proceedings of Symposia in Pure Mathematics, Vol. XXVIII, AMS, Providence, 1976. And after such a consultation it becomes obvious that Gleason, Montgomery and Zippin did not at all answer fully - but only partially, even if ... gloriously ... :-) :-) :-) - the true question of Hilbert. Perhaps it may be appropriate to rem

Comment: @ElemerERosinger From now on, let's make appropriate use of answer boxes: to answer mathematical questions. I have converted your "answer" to a comment; it got truncated however. I'll leave it to you to add the remainder, if you care. Next time such an answer will be deleted outright.

Comment: @Elemer: I did look at the article just now.  As the article states, it is reasonable to construe Hilbert's slightly imprecise question as asking about differentiability of topological *transformation* groups acting on manifolds.  But the case of a locally Euclidean topological group acting on itself is obviously an important special case of this.  In other words, everyone agrees that how to tell whether a topological group is a Lie group *was* asked by Hilbert: the issue is whether he may have asked for more than this (and whether he did or not, the more general question remains open).

Comment: Thus Mariano's assertion that Hilbert asked this question and that it (this question) was answered fully by Gleason, Montgomery and Zippin is certainly true.  Thus you have no valid bone to pick with anything that Mariano actually said.  Does this leave anything relevant to this question for you to comment on?